# I'm credited for an answer I didn't write

Tags: bug

On the answer *[How can I get the ICCID number of the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751823/how-can-i-get-the-iccid-number-of-the-phone/38032034#38032034)* (now deleted)

I left a comment:

> This answer isn't mine. Look at the edit history of my other answer for the source
> – Reed Jun 25 '16 at 19:08

If memory serves... At that time, the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38032034/revisions) showed somebody else as the OP of the answer, but it doesn't anymore.

I'm guessing the original answerer deleted their account or something? I don't really care about the reputation one way or the other, but I don't deserve credit for the answer... Though I guess that doesn't really matter much either. It seems weird though.

Is there a way to fix this? Making it a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer or something?

Comment: Looking at the revision history of [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9752396/revisions) it looks like you removed the edit somebody made to your first answer and turned it into a separate one. Maybe you meant to make it CW at the time but forgot?

Comment: Well it's your answer, even if you didn't originally author it, you can make it a community answer by clicking the "Community Wiki" checkbox when editing it if you so choose

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I don't know what I was thinking back then lol. Maybe I'll delete the answer that's not accepted & put it back into my original answer, then make it a community wiki.

Comment: Oh, gosh. And even today, looking at it, I misread my comment, which said edit history of my "other" answer. Oof

Comment: I'm curious as to why you find it important. You've linked and credited the other users involved, so there's no confusion. Is it the reputation points that bother you?

Comment: @Scratte It's probably just a matter of integrity.

Comment: @Scratte, TylerH pretty much nailed it, not that it's a huge deal either way. I got an upvote for it yesterday, which is what brought my attention to it. It is community wiki now. Though, I certainly didn't mind having extra rep' points to throw at bounties from time to time lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no evidence that the second answer was posted by someone else. It all points that you wrote both answers, but you don't remember. I [went back in time to 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220132702/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751823/how-can-i-get-the-iccid-number-of-the-phone) and it says that both answers were posted by a user named Jakar who is you.

Other possible options:

- the answer was moved after a question merger, but that would be listed in the timeline
- you posted it from a sock-puppet account which later got merged with your account.

What you can do now is delete the unaccepted answer and edit the other one with the updated information. After all you are listed as the owner of both answers.

Comment: The second answer was originally a suggested edit that got approved on OPs original answer. OP removed that edit to their answer and posted it as a _new_ answer. So while it was _posted_ by them, it was not _written_ by them.